# Pushing counter value to array to create a string with previous values

Tags: javascript, methods

"use strict";

```
let count = 0;
let totalPassengerCount = 0;
let entries = [];

const saveCount = document.getElementById("save-count");

const countEl = document.getElementById("count-el");

const resetCount = document.getElementById("reset-count");

document
  .getElementById("incremenet-btn")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    count += 1;
    countEl.innerHTML = count;
```

});

```
 document.getElementById("save-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  totalPassengerCount += count;
  entries = count.push([0]);
  count = 0;
  countEl.innerHTML = count;

  saveCount.innerHTML = totalPassengerCount;
});

resetCount.addEventListener("click", function () {
  totalPassengerCount = 0;
  count = 0;
  countEl.innerHTML = count;

  saveCount.innerHTML = totalPassengerCount;
});

const entry = document.getElementById("entry-info");

console.log(entries);
```

I am trying to push each saved count into an array to display as a message, however I am running into a problem where it's not actually doing it, I am fairly new to coding. All help is appreciated.

Comment: not sure what the rest is but to push to entries it should be `entries.push(count);`, rtm: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you for that, for some reason I thought it was done differently.

Comment: yeah, don't do `entries = `, else it will reset entries to a number, return value is the length of the array